# postgresql query year (integer) field equals year of current date

Tags: postgresql, date, extract

This seems like it should be fairly simple and straight forward but I haven't yet found the right combination. I have a column called last_assess_yr that is an integer. I am trying to find all rows from my_table where '01-01' + 'year' < current_date and give them a value in a new column. I have the following:

```
    SELECT last_assess_yr,
    CASE
    WHEN format('01-01-%s'::text, last_assess_yr)::timestamp without time 
    zone < current_date 
    THEN YES 
    ELSE NO 
    END AS assess_value
    FROM my__table
```

but, the results are not correct

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need to convert the integer into a timestamp, you could just compare the extracted year to the integer.

```
select 
    case when last_assess_yr < extract('year' from current_date)::int 
         then 'YES' else 'NO' 
    end
```

However for reference the following will work:

```
select 
    case when format('01-01-%s'::text, 2017)::timestamp < current_date 
         then 'YES' else 'NO' 
    end
```

i.e. you do not need to remove time (of day) when you convert a string of '01-01-2017' to a timestamp.

and: I assume YES and NO also need to be treated as literals: 'YES' and 'NO'

Comment: I suspect you know the solution and maybe I was confusing in my example. I have to format the 'year' to a specific date (not really Jan 1 - but a specific MM-DD-) and then see if it is < then the current date. I considered your first option when building the query but it has to format to a specific day of a specific month. Your second option confuses me just because it specifies '2017'.....but the whole date querying has proven to be challenging for me.

Comment: a lot depends on how that MM-DD- is provided. as 1 string? as 2 integers? Pity you didn't actually ask the question you really needed to ask. For your next question please provide **sample data**  ... suggested reading:  [Why should I provide a MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query). *By the way I detest MM-DD-YYYY as a date format, I am not one of the ~10% of the world you uses it.*

Comment: I did provide an example from the sample data --- I just provided a simple MMDD that needs to be 'concatenated' onto the year when running the query -- maybe I should have put '05-05'. You can hate the date format all you want. Its not my database and the other date columns within the db are formatted that way --- so I try to be consistent in my queries. I'll spread the message far and wide. Thx for the reading material. I shall push forward trying to resolve my issue.

Comment: You provided a single constant `"01-01"`, I don't consider that to be "data", You also do not identify if "mm-dd" is a single string, 2 strings, 2 integers etc.  nor where this/those values come from.  Try putting yourself in the role of answering your question. (*You will find there isn't much detail to work with.*)

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else is looking, this worked for me:

```
    WHEN last_assess_yr > 0 AND format('%s-05-05'::text, w.last_assess_yr)::timestamp < 
    current_date THEN 'yes' 
    ELSE 'no' 
    END
```